# org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: Invoice column: INVOICE_ID

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

Hibernate is saying that mapping for the column INVOICE_ID is repeated. But I am unable to understand this exception. Please Help !!
        My Invoice class is given below :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="INVOICES")
    public class Invoice {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="INVOICE_ID", nullable=false,insertable=false,updatable=false)
        private Integer invoice_id;

        @Column(name="Date_Created", nullable=false)
        private Timestamp dateCreated;

        @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
        private String description;

        @Column(name="Total_Amount")
        private Double totalAmount;

        @Column(name="Tax_Amount")
        private Double taxAmount;

        @Column(name="Due_Date")
        private Timestamp dueDate;

        @Column(name="deleted")
        private boolean deleted;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="Invoice_Item_Detail_id", nullable=false)
        private InvoiceItemsDetails invoiceItemsDetails;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="ID", nullable=false)
        private Client client;


        public Client getClient() {
            return client;
        }

        public void setClient(Client client) {
            this.client = client;
        }

        public Date getDueDate() {
            return dueDate;
        }

        public void setDueDate(Timestamp dueDate) {
            this.dueDate = dueDate;
        }


    /*  public Integer getInvoice_id() {
            return invoice_id;
        }

        public void setInvoice_id(Integer invoice_id) {
            this.invoice_id = invoice_id;
        }
    */
        public Date getDateCreated() {
            return dateCreated;
        }

        public void setDateCreated(Timestamp dateCreated) {
            this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public Double getTotalAmount() {
            return totalAmount;
        }

        public void setTotalAmount(Double totalAmount) {
            this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
        }

        public Double getTaxAmount() {
            return taxAmount;
        }

        public void setTaxAmount(Double taxAmount) {
            this.taxAmount = taxAmount;
        }

        public boolean isDeleted() {
            return deleted;
        }

        public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
            this.deleted = deleted;
        }


        public InvoiceItemsDetails getInvoiceItemsDetails() {
            return invoiceItemsDetails;
        }

        public void setInvoiceItemsDetails(InvoiceItemsDetails invoiceItemsDetails) {
            this.invoiceItemsDetails = invoiceItemsDetails;
        }   

    }
```

I have used INVOICE_ID as foreign key in USERS table as given below :

```
@OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="INVOICE_ID", nullable=false)
    public Set<Invoice> getInvoices() {
        return invoices;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This mapping makes no sense to me.

How could the INVOICE_ID column of the table INVOICE (which is its primary key) serve as a foreign key to the USER.ID column?

There should be a USER_ID column in INVOICE, and this column should serve as a JoinColumn for your OneToMany association:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", nullable=false)
public Set<Invoice> getInvoices() {
    return invoices;
}
```